# FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, hiveql

I'm running

- apache-hive-1.2.1-bin
- hadoop-2.7.1
- spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6

I was able to configure hive on Spark but when I try to execute a query it gives me below error msg.

```
hive> SELECT COUNT(*) AS rcount, yom From service GROUP BY yom;
Query ID = hduser_20160110105649_4c90528a-76ba-4127-8849-54f2152be817
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
Starting Spark Job = b9cbbd47-f41f-48b5-98c3-efcaa145390e
Status: SENT
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but I did not configure yarn because of some jobs are running. I am not sure that is the solution of the problem.

```
yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler
```

Have you configured yarn like the document said?

Comment: Where should this configuration go?

Answer (score -1):

yarn-site.xml:

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class</name>
   <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler</value>
</property>
```